# Use global replace method in Angular 2+ component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to add a new property called "dataTestValue" to an existing component. This is a simple component that acts like a tab:

```
export class TabComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input('active') active = false;
  @Input('title') title: string;

  dataTestValue: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataTestValue = this.title.replace('/ /g', '_');
    console.log(this.dataTestValue);
  }
```

}

Because the "title" property can contain blanks I need to replace and convert it to lowercase.

I manage to replace only the first blank by using this:

```
this.dataTestValue = this.title.replace(' ', '_');
```

By some reason the global method doesn't work, it just prints the original value. Any ideas?

P.S: If I'm using the "ngOnInit" lifecycle hook please inform me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the single quotes from the regex:

```
this.dataTestValue = this.title.replace(/ /g, '_');
```

Comment: Works. Sorry for my poor JavaScript skills

Answer (score 1):

Either remove the quotes

```
this.dataTestValue = this.title.replace(/ /g, '_');
```

Or you can use this too

```
this.dataTestValue = this.title.replace(/\s+/g, '_');
```